# Draw cross on a picture box and get center coordinates EMGU c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I learn and now I am in a dilemma, silly, but for the newbie a dilemma, I have not been able to draw a line in the shape of a cross in my video window and that allows me to know the coordinates of the center of that cross.

I show you the current window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvilD.png)

and then how I want it to look

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwct4.png)

I have searched in forums, youtube and more, but I can't find a simple example that will help me
It is an idea of ​​what I need, thank you very much for your help and patience

this is my code. They will notice how inexperienced I am

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace Farmer_v._0._1._0
{
    public partial class Vision_artificial : Form

    {

        //COLOR PICKER
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);
        //COLOR PICKER


        Emgu.CV.Capture capWebcam = null;
        bool blnCapturingInProcess = false;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgOriginal;
        
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgProcesada;
        Mat frame = new Mat();

         
        
        



        //canny
        double umbral11 = 300;
        double umbral22= 300;
        //circulos
        double min_distancia = 4;
        double umbralCirculos1 = 1;
        double umbralCirculos2 = 1;
        int min_diametro = 10;
        int max_diametro = 400;
        int n_circulos = 0;
        //BGR
        int B1 = 0;
        int G1 = 0;
        int R1 = 175;
        int B2 = 100;
        int G2 = 100;
        int R2 = 256;



        public Vision_artificial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          

        }
        public Color GetColorAt(Point location)
        {
            using (Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
            {
                using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
                {
                    using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(ibOriginal.Handle))
                    {
                        IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
                        IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
                        int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                        gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                        gsrc.ReleaseHdc();

                        
                    }
                }

                return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
            }
        }

        public void Draw(Cross2DF cross, IColor color, int thickness)
        {

        }

        private void Vision_artificial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                capWebcam = new Emgu.CV.Capture(1);  //asociar captura de objeto a la camara por defecto
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException except)    //si hay error
            {
                txtXYRadius.Text = except.Message;  //muestra error de objeto en el cuadro de texto
                return;
            }

            Application.Idle += processFrameAndUpdateGUI;
            blnCapturingInProcess = true;

            //camara.ImageGrabbed += Grabar;
            //camara.Start();
        


        }

        private void Vision_artificial_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (capWebcam != null)
            {
                capWebcam.Dispose();

            }
        }



        void processFrameAndUpdateGUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            imgOriginal = capWebcam.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();


            if (imgOriginal == null) return;
            imgProcesada = imgOriginal.InRange(new Bgr(B1, G1, R1),
                                            new Bgr(B2, G2, R2));
            imgProcesada = imgProcesada.SmoothGaussian(9);




            CircleF[] circles = imgProcesada.HoughCircles(new Gray(100),
                                                            new Gray(50),
                                                            2,
                                                            imgProcesada.Height / min_distancia,
                                                            min_diametro,
                                                            max_diametro)[0];
          

            foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
            {
                if (txtXYRadius.Text != "") txtXYRadius.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                txtXYRadius.AppendText("Objeto en posicion x=" + circle.Center.X.ToString().PadLeft(4) +
                                                       ", y =" + circle.Center.Y.ToString().PadLeft(4) +
                                           ", radius =" + circle.Radius.ToString("###.000").PadLeft(7));

                txtXYRadius.ScrollToCaret();
                n_circulos = circles.Length;
                geoX.Text = circle.Center.X.ToString();
                geoY.Text = circle.Center.Y.ToString();


                CvInvoke.Circle(imgOriginal,
                                new Point((int)circle.Center.X, (int)circle.Center.Y),
                                3,
                                new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0),
                                -1,
                                Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.FourConnected,
                                0);

                imgOriginal.Draw(circle,
                                    new Bgr(Color.Red),
                                    3);
               

            }

            //Mat imagen2 = new Mat();
            //CvInvoke.Canny(imgOriginal.Clone(), imagen2, umbral11, umbral22);
            //ibCanny.Image = imagen2.Bitmap;
            ////circles = CvInvoke.HoughCircles(imagen2, HoughType.Gradient, 1.0, min_distancia, umbralCirculos1, umbralCirculos2, min_diametro, max_diametro);
            //

            //for (int i = 0; i < circles.Length; i++)
            //{

            //    CvInvoke.Circle(imagen2,
            //        Point.Round(circles[i].Center), (int)circles[i].Radius, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar, 2, LineType.EightConnected, 0);

            //}



           

            ibOriginal.Image = imgOriginal.ToBitmap();
            ibProcesada.Image = imgProcesada.ToBitmap();
            




        }

        //private void Grabar (object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    Mat imagen = new Mat();
        //    camara.Retrieve(imagen, 0);




        //        ibOriginal.Image = imagen.Bitmap;





        //    Mat imagen2 = new Mat();
        //    CvInvoke.Canny(imagen.Clone(), imagen2, umbral11, umbral22);
        //    ibProcesada.Image = imagen2.Bitmap;

        //    CircleF[] circulos = CvInvoke.HoughCircles(imagen2.Clone(), HoughType.Gradient, 1.0, min_distancia, umbralCirculos1, umbralCirculos2, min_diametro, max_diametro);
        //    n_circulos = circulos.Length;

        //    Mat imagen3 =imagen.Clone();

        //    for (int i = 0; i < circulos.Length; i++)
        //    {

        //        CvInvoke.Circle(imagen3,
        //            Point.Round(circulos[i].Center), (int)circulos[i].Radius, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar, 2, LineType.EightConnected, 0);

        //    }

        //    ibCanny.Image = imagen3.Bitmap;


        //}

        private void Arduino(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }




        public Bitmap CannyEdge(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> Cannybmp;
            Image<Gray, Byte> GrayBmp;
            Image<Bgr, Byte> orig = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> imgSmooth;
            Bitmap output;

            imgSmooth = orig.PyrUp();
            imgSmooth._SmoothGaussian(3);
            GrayBmp = imgSmooth.Convert<Gray, byte>();

            Gray grayCannyThreshold = new Gray(umbral11);
            Gray grayThreshLinking = new Gray(umbral22);

            Cannybmp = GrayBmp.Canny(grayCannyThreshold.Intensity, grayThreshLinking.Intensity);
            
           

                output = Cannybmp.ToBitmap();
            //int a = 5;
            return output;

        }

        private void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            
        }

     

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void btnPausa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (blnCapturingInProcess == true)
            {
                Application.Idle -= processFrameAndUpdateGUI;
                blnCapturingInProcess = false;
                btnPausa.Text = "Capturar";
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Idle += processFrameAndUpdateGUI;
                blnCapturingInProcess = true;
                btnPausa.Text = "Pausa";
            }
        }

        private void ibCanny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            umbral11 = (double)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }

        private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            umbral22 = (double)numericUpDown2.Value;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbln_circulos.Text = n_circulos.ToString();
        }

        private void numericUpDown5_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            umbralCirculos1 = (double)num_umbral_1.Value;
        }

        private void num_distanicia_minima_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            min_distancia = (double)num_distancia_minima.Value;
        }

        private void num_umbral_2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            umbralCirculos2 = (double)num_umbral_2.Value;
        }

        private void num_diametro_minimo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            min_diametro = (int)num_diametro_minimo.Value;
        }

        private void num_diametro_maximo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            max_diametro = (int)num_diametro_maximo.Value;
        }

      

        private void boxB1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            B1 = (int)boxB1.Value;
        }

        private void boxG1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            G1 = (int)boxG1.Value;
        }

        private void boxR1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            R1 = (int)boxG1.Value;
        }

        private void boxB2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            B2 = (int)boxB2.Value;
        }

        private void boxG2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            G2 = (int)boxG2.Value;
        }

        private void boxR2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            R2 = (int)boxR2.Value;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
        }

        private void ibOriginal_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            

        }

        private void ibOriginal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panelColor.BackColor = GetColorAt(e.Location);

            
            

            //Bitmap pixelData = new Bitmap (ibOriginal.Image);
            //Color clr = pixelData.GetPixel(Cursor.Position.X - this.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - (this.Top +15));
            //lblB.Text = "RGBA(" + clr.R.ToString() + ", " + clr.G.ToString() + ", " + clr.B.ToString();

            



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code contains no mention of any "line" calls. why? -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. you presented over 400 lines of code. that's not an MRE by any measure.

Comment: Hello, that is precisely what I am asking, how is the cross line made? that's what the question is about, and put the code so they know what it's about